# Azure Logic app - Twilio connector

Tags: http, azure, twilio

How to configure Twilio connector with HTTP listener in azure for to invoke messaging service

Answer (score 1):

Please elaborate your question (is there any problem occurs?), because Twilio connector can be connected just with the Key/Password.

If you need to invoke Mobile App, then you should add HTTP Listener with the needed verb selected (get,post, etc).

[image]